# Update Multiple Dropdowns(5drop) values with the same name in jQuery and values comes dynamically from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dropdown, laravel-9

[image: firs image, dropdown with loop, here are 3 dropdwonsValues that i want to update or load those drop downs]

1st dropdown values(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
second  dropdown values(25, 26, 27, 28, 29)
third dropdown values(35, 36, 37, 38, 39)

```
I want every drop down to be loaded with that data and it is  dropdown, the data needs to be loaded dynamically or automatically to get the update.
```

```
$('select[name="SubCategoryID[]"] option').each(function (e, v) {
  if (val.SubCategoryID == v.value) {
    console.log('', v.value); 
    $(`select[name="SubCategoryID[]"] option value`).find(v.value).val(v.value) 
  } else { 
  }
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### i got the solution, the code is below

```
       $('select[name="SubCategoryID[]"] option').each(function (e, v) {

                        if (val.SubCategoryID == v.value) {
                            console.log('dropdown', $(this).val());
                            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                            $(`select[name="SubCategoryID[]"] option value`).find(v.value).val(v.value)
                        } else {
                            // console.log('Done');
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).